# Adding word links in custom dictionary from chat acronyms to real words

Tags: dictionary, grammar

I read that I could add custom words to Mac OS X's spellcheck dictionary by either:

1. Right clicking the word and selecting 'learn spelling'
2. Adding them manually to 'LocalDictionary' in the user library folder

I added the chat acronym 'ur' to mean 'your' (sometimes 'you are', but that's a different issue). Now that 'ur' is added as a word it won't be marked incorrect with the red underline.

Is there a way for me to add a 'link' or something else that will alter the spellcheck so that the grammar check will treat 'ur' as 'your'?